# JupyterLab keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

I recently switched from Jupyter Notebook to JupyterLab - None on the keyboard shortcuts appear to be working (Including ESC). The same shortcuts appear to be working on Jupyter notebook.

I am using JupyterLab 2.0.0 on Windows 10, Conda 4.8.3, Chrome Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am running JupyterLab on `http://localhost:8888/lab` and NB on `http://localhost:8888/notebooks`

When I open the browser console, I see this message:

[image]

Edit:

1. Below is a screenshot of the current setting:
   [image]

Comment: Did you try enabling the setting which it says is disabled and prevents executing the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have not made any changes or manually enabled/disabled any settings. It is running on default settings. I have added a  screenshot of the settings to the question - none of the assigned keyboard shortcuts are working.

Comment: I would try upgrading to 2.2.4; in general I would not use 2.0.0 given it was immediately followed by point releases (as common with major releases of software).